# barcode scanner polling

Tags: java, barcode-scanner

I am working with a bar code scanner and java currently. i wanted to know wether there is a possibility to poll this device.

What I want: a popup message every time you scan a barcode

What I dont want: is to focus a text field first to do so.

I want this to run in the background so that the user only has to scan something without anything in focus. is this possible?
in other words, i dont want to use it like a keyboard but more like a sensor that informs me every time a new value is available.

thank in advance

Comment: I just answered a similar question in depth [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146840/barcode-scanner-implementation-on-java), with an example of my implementation (I didn't want to use a keyboard hook because I didn't want to require focus on the program before interpreting a scan).

Answer (score 0):

i think these mostly work as keyboard input.

you could probably create a KeyListener() to check for the incoming values.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can listen barcode scanning detection on your whole hardware at anytime example:PC or Laptop or Tablet etc.

For that you need to add barcode scanner listener on your main file which is available to all the pages or all the urls of your application.

You can use my custome script from my answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73896680/14870617)

Comment: Please share more details, like sample code. What kind of "page" are you talking about?

Comment: Ohk I have added a my post link

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer instead of linking to other questions. If this is a duplicate of the other question, please mark it as such

Comment: Rather than give negative feedback you can edit my post if I missed something on post. Thank you for your appreciation.

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer on your own if you want to share more details. If I had an answer, I would post it, but Java is not my strongest point.